# Upload and Deploy code in Rococo Contract (Testnet) and Shibuya Testnet not working?

Tags: ink, rococo, cross-contract-call, shibuya

I am experimenting with cross contract with a combination of psp22 and psp37 in my project. But there is a problem when uploading json file and wasm file and deploying. It just shows the "contracts.instantiateWithCode broadcast" message and no further action takes place. But the transaction count in Account is increased by 1. But no contract is executed. How do I fix it
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info ?
- your AccountId
- can you try on https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/add-contract ?
- the block number or hash of your call

Comment: @P.Ossun i try in contracts-ui.substrate.io/add-contract. When i deploy cross contract, it not response nothing (It just white UI). 
Here is my AccountID in Shibuya Testnet: b9ihwaTv7658Wf7ekTVdzevDq6grVE6QEDUQiCdsYMzVJcn

Comment: @P.Ossun I sent you 3 contract i using to deploy to contract in Shibuya Testnet: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EYtlChnHFggsfDpXLLwzhuEmTY-Gfd5_?usp=sharing
Can't you help me deploy 3 contract in Shibuya Testnet or Rococo Testnet Contract.

Comment: Try to deploy in contracts-ui : https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/contract/
I think polkadotjs apps didnt implement weight version 2 now

Comment: @CocDap I have to try on contracts-ui.substrate.io/contract. But cross contract failed when deploy. It don't return anything, UI is completely empty.

Comment: It was successfully uploaded & instantiated:
https://shibuya.subscan.io/account/b9ihwaTv7658Wf7ekTVdzevDq6grVE6QEDUQiCdsYMzVJcn
And this is the latest contract address you have deployed:
https://shibuya.subscan.io/account/abTb7kFLYoef7eNMJPHN4AvQVZgVjhuXUZ2oS5CiRYmhmXG?tab=transfer

What is the issue exactly ?

Comment: @P.Ossun Like i said at the beginning. It was successfully & instantiated, but it just loading like figure 1. It dont show constructor or contract to interact in tab Contract. And in contract-ui, I deploy successfully 2 contract is nft contract and native contract, I want to using hash address 2 contract nft and native contract for use in dmp contract. but when deploy it failed (UI dont show anything, Empty UI like Figure 4).